# Adding data to Mongodb collection giving error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cloud9-ide

I am using cloud 9 ide for developing nodejs app. In that I am using mongodb.

I have created database and it is connecting successfully. Now I am going to add record to collection as belw

```
app.post('/ajax-mongo-connect', function (req, res) {
    MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/sedd", function (err, db){

        if(!err) {
            console.log("Mongo Connected.");
            db.test.insert({ item: "card", qty: 15 });
            //console.log(drp);
            res.send('connected');
        } else {
            console.log("Mongo not Connected");
            res.send('error');
        }

    }); 
})
```

When trying to insert `{ item: "card", qty: 15 }` to test collection. The error occurs as below

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/mongo_client.js:475                                                                                       
      throw err                                                                                                                                               
            ^                                                                                                                                                 
TypeError: Cannot call method 'insert' of undefined                                                                                                               
at /home/ubuntu/workspace/server.js:105:21                                                                                                                    
at _finishConnecting (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/mongo_client.js:472:11)                                                         
at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
```

**Cannot call method 'insert' of undefined**

Why I am getting this error. Please help

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using the MongoDB Node driver based on the code snippet you provided. You need to define db. I will give you a general example

Replace

```
db.test.insert({ item: "card", qty: 15 });
```

with something like

```
db.test('collectionName').insert({'key':'value'},callback(err,inserted){'error checking'})
```

hope this helps.

Read this for more details (http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/)